# Problems with bodies and strings Chrono Engine

Tags: c++

I have been working on this function for a while now. It is part of a Chrono Engine program. It is supposed to take in a string and for each letter create a new body in the world, add a texture, set the orientation, and make it collidable. In terms of adding bodies to the world, I have isolated the problem down to the code letters[i] + ".obj". I also try creating a string, setting it to the desired one and appending the desired file extension. My output code is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wReU.jpg). Also, when I try to add a texture, the texture cannot be found.

void assemble_letters(ChIrrApp& application, std::string letters) {

```
for (int i = 0; i < letters.length(); i++) {
    ChSharedPtr<ChBody> letterBody(new ChBody());
    ChSharedPtr<ChObjShapeFile> lettermesh(new ChObjShapeFile);
    ChSharedPtr<ChObjShapeFile> lettertexture(new ChObjShapeFile);

    std::string str;
    str = letters;

    lettermesh->SetFilename(GetChronoDataFile(str.append(".obj")));
    lettertexture->SetFilename(GetChronoDataFile("RedTexture.png"));

    std::cout << "NNNNNNNNNNNNN" << std::endl;
    std::cout << letters[i] + ".obj" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "NNNNNNNNNNNNN" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "AAAAAAAA" << std::endl;
    std::cout << letters << std::endl;
    std::cout << "AAAAAAAA" << std::endl;

    letterBody->AddAsset(lettermesh);
    letterBody->SetBodyFixed(true);
    letterBody->RecomputeCollisionModel();
    letterBody->SetCollide(true);
    letterBody->SetPos(ChVector<>( 0, .5, 0));
    letterBody->SetRot(Q_from_AngAxis(90, ChVector<>((3.1415926/2), 0, 0)));
    letterBody->AddAsset(lettertexture);

    application.GetSystem()->Add(letterBody);

    application.AssetBind(letterBody);
    application.AssetUpdate(letterBody);

    letterlist.push_back(letterBody);


};
```

}

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is. But did you really mean to write `letters[i] + ".obj"`? I assume `letters[i]` is a `char`, so the concatenation semantics you're after don't exist, and I don't understand why you don't just continue using the stream insertion operator `<<` as you're already doing twice in the same line. But without a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a clear problem statement, I cannot write an answer...

Comment: I did try to use 'letters[i] + ".obj"'. If you look at the output code, it does not correspond to what should be printed at all.

Comment: Yeah I can see that's what you wrote in your program, but I'm asking whether it was an accident, because it's not correct. Stick to the stream insertion operator `<<`.